# why "InnerClass cannot be resolved or is not a field"?

Tags: java, class

This Question is some tiny part of the big Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68580188/how-can-i-provide-this-sort-of-string-builder-class), but maybe it's too big?

Code here:

```
public class Test3 {
    public static class OuterClass {
        public static String str;

        public static class InnerClass {
            public static final String str = "innen";
        }

        public static InnerClass InnerClass() {
            return new InnerClass();
        }
    }

    public static OuterClass OuterClass(String value) {
        OuterClass.str = "aussen_".concat(value);
        return new OuterClass();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(OuterClass("1").str);
        System.out.println(OuterClass("1").InnerClass().str);
        System.out.println(OuterClass("1").InnerClass.str); // Error: InnerClass cannot be resolved or is not a field
    }
}
```

I know, I return an Object of Class OuterClass, which itself has Variables and Methods but no Class.
So the Question is: what could I return in the OuterClass(String) Method so that it can be used like the Class OuterClass itself (like in the main Function)?

Comment: Why are you spamming `static` all over the place? How about making `InnerClass` non static? (I didn't really understand what you're trying to do in the original post)

Comment: because I don't really need different Objects of this Class.
See main Method. It is not ment to ever store a Object of the Class. It will just be used to build a String and finish.
Yeah, Original Post is a little bit longer^^ Again there: see Main Method. If you copy the Code at least into Eclipse (its super easy to find all resources, because the Path will be proposed like that. But the Question why I want it like that is in the Original Question. Here ist only the Question: how can I do it like that.

Comment: Oh I think I get what the whole "different directories" thing was all about. Sounds like you just want the builder pattern. "because I don't really need different Objects of this Class" Umm, but you ***are*** creating `OuterClass` objects, potentially multiple ones too... Making the inner class non-static will allow you to access it. See also: [Should we avoid object creation in Java?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149563/should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java)

Comment: tried that too. Error remains.
But I will study your mentioned Quesion

Comment: I'm writing an answer for your original post anyway. There is a _much_ better way of doing this.

Comment: thanks! that wouldn't make this Question irrelevant, but relevance shrinks down to 4%^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235440/discussion-between-dino-and-sweeper).